# How to make a div that displays table-row-group vertically scrollable?

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

I am building a table using only divs with the help of the css `table` display property(ies). I need my table to be flexible so I cannot use `<table>`.
Everything works fine except for .table-body. I set the display property to `table-row-group` so it behaves like a `<tbody>` but I want it to be scrollable. I set its overflow property to auto and it still does not work.

For example, I have this table:

```
        <div class="table">
        <div class="table-header">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">Header 1</div>
                <div class="table-cell">Header 2</div>
                <div class="table-cell">Header 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="table-body">
            <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">cell 1</div>
                <div class="table-cell">cell 2</div>
                <div class="table-cell">cell 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the css for `.table-body`. I added a display property of `table-row-group` so it behaves like a `<tbody>`. It still does not have a scroll even with overflow set to auto.

```
    .table-body {
        display: table-row-group; // makes it behave like <tbody>
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto; // does nothing
    }
```

Comment: You need to use fixed width to enable horizontal scroll.

Comment: @SifatHaque Thanks, but I don't need horizontal scroll for now. I need vertical scroll.

Comment: Then you can just use a fixed height for your `.table-body` class instead of `100%` and you need to use `display: block`

Comment: I can't do `display: block` because I'm already doing `display: table-row-group` and I cannot do `<tbody>` like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

We need the following steps in order to achieve **vertical scrolling**:
1. Setting `<tbody>` to `display:block` so that we can apply the height and overflow property.
2. Setting the `<thead><tr>` to `display:block`.

But, since you are already using `display` property to set to table-related display values, I am not sure how can we apply two display values to a `div`.

You can achieve what you need using a slightly different approach though, like:

```css
.fixed_header{
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.